# Continue without user consent (Azure WebApp)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, asp.net-authentication

I have an azure web app with static and dynamic (incrementally) scopes. The static scopes have an admin consent for the whole organization, so these will not bother the end-users.

The dynamic scopes are relevant only for one specific feature. If the user decides to not consent here, the application should just continue. This feature will of course not be usable but that is not a concern.

I tried to handle this scenario via `OnRemoteFailure` or via `OnAccessDenied`; something like this:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    // More events here
    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
}
```

But that did not help unfortunately. I am still getting this ugly error message

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error:
> 'access_denied' [...]

It seems like I am missing something big here. Can someone point me in the right direction? How can the user continue to use the app without consenting to these dynamic scopes?

Comment: Do you think a catch block for OpenIdConnectProtocolException inside which you add the logic to continue the app will help here?

Comment: Actually I don't know. Where would this catch block be? I am getting an error back from azure so I thought that this is my "catch block" where I can now decide how to handle this error. From my perspective, I even think that my code should just work fine. But it doesn't ;)

Comment: Try debugging and see if it's going inside your onRemoteFailure method. The exception is unhandled because you don't have a try-catch block to handle it. https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_exceptions.asp